# Why does this .htaccess code do a constant redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

The title explains most of it. I'm using WAMP.
I have a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*)  /?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And a index.php with the following contents:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET)
?>
```

Also, I get the following apache_error.log error:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

If your confused on what I'm doing, I'm trying to make a cms where index.php processes all other pages and it self(I barely started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing infinite looping because `%{REQUEST_URI}` remains empty even after rewrite to `/?uri-...`

You should be checking `%{QUERY_SRING}` instead to check for presence of query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)uri= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ah I had a typo, it is fixed now. Please try again with updated rule.